# Factory pattern register method c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stl, tags, factory

Im trying to apply factory pattern on my application

```
typedef TagSystemBase* (*TagSystemFactoryCreate) (void);
typedef map<string,TagSystemFactoryCreate> FactoryMap;

class TagSystem
{


  private:

   static TagSystemBase *sys;

   TagSystem(){};
   virtual ~TagSystem(){};

  public:

 static FactoryMap  tagsyss;
   static TagSystemBase*  init(string nm);
   static const TagSystemBase * instance();
   static void  free();

inline static void  RegTagSys(string nm, TagSystemFactoryCreate fnptr)
{
  if ( fnptr && nm == "" )
   return;

  TagSystem::tagsyss.insert(std::pair<string,TagSystemFactoryCreate>(nm,fnptr));
}

};

//------------------

#include "FactoryItemConstructor.h"

class InTouch10 : public TagSystemBase, public FactoryItem<InTouch10>
{
    public:
        InTouch10();
        virtual ~InTouch10();

        virtual string name() const;
    protected:
    private:

};


TagSystem::RegTagSys("InTouch10", InTouch10::createInstance);


#endif // INTOUCH10_H
```

At the  "TagSystem::RegTagSys("InTouch10", InTouch10::createInstance);"
line i got this error from the compiler
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Is it possible to regist my class to the factory class right after
its definition? I think i have seen something similar in some c++ api (Qt)...

Zui

Comment: *blink blink* are you trying to call a static function at global scope?  Shouldn't that line be in a main?

Comment: (Actually, scratch that, to do it the way you are doing you need a static member with a constructor that has the side effect of registering it to the TagSystem. This design is...weird).

Comment: Ok I was wrong with that static function really. I remembered to qDeclareMetaType<T>() and Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, but after I have seen its implementation/definition...I changed my mind:

Answer (score 0):

```
        class TagSystemBase
    {

        protected:

            TagAttributeTypeSet sup_attrs; //supported attribute types
            TagTypeSet          sup_types; //supported types;
            /*Called in constructor of this class's subclasses to register supported TagTypes*/
            void regTagType(string basenm, TagTypeLen len, TagAttributeTypeSet sattrs, string aliasnm);
            /*Called in constructor of this class's subclasses to register supported TagAttributeTypes*/
            void regTagAttributeType(string nm, set<string> pval,TagAttributeType::TagAttributeBaseTypes bt);
        public:

           TagSystemBase();
          virtual ~TagSystemBase();
          virtual string name() const  = 0;

          bool getTagTypeByName(string nm, TagType &tt) const;
          bool getTagAttributeTypeByName(string nm, TagAttributeType &tat) const ;
          TagAttributeTypeSet supportedAttributeTypes() const;
          TagTypeSet supportedTypes() const;

    };



    typedef TagSystemBase* (*TagSystemFactoryCreate) (void);
    typedef map<string,TagSystemFactoryCreate> FactoryMap;

    class TagSystem
    {


      private:
        static FactoryMap  tagsyss;
       static TagSystemBase *sys;

       TagSystem(){};
       virtual ~TagSystem(){};

      public:


       static TagSystemBase*  init(string nm);
       static const TagSystemBase * instance();
       static void  free();
       static void  reg(string nm, TagSystemFactoryCreate fnptr );



    };


        template <typename T>
        void  regTagSys(string nm)
        {
          TagSystem::reg(nm,&T::createInstance);
        }



    template <class T>
    class TagSystemFactoryItem : public TagSystemBase
    {

      public:

       static TagSystemBase * createInstance()
       {
            return new T;
       }


    };

class InTouch10 :  public TagSystemFactoryItem<InTouch10>
{
    public:
        InTouch10();
        virtual ~InTouch10();

        virtual string name() const;
    protected:
    private:

};
```

I wanted to have something like [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://blog.debao.me/2013/06/qt-macro-q-declare-metatype/), but Im fine with my
regTagSys("InTouch10") solution Ill put it somewhere to be called only once.